# UI stuck with universal application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, xcode-instruments

I have created two separate apps i.e. for iPhone and ipad.both are working fine individually.Now i merged them into universal app by creating two appdelegate files in main.m .I am using one .mm viewcontroller which is common for both in universal app.(.mm file includes iMag swiper Sdk).Now my problem is that my universal app stucks on iPhone on random screens.It works well on iPad.

i am new to using instrument. i have used instruments for knowing memory problems.i found out that when my UI stucks ,live bytes memory goes on increasing.initial live bytes are upto 6 mbs.But when stucks it goes on increasing.Screenshots of instruments is attached below.

[image]

Thanks in Advance